# MySQL access - allow remote access or via PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, database-connection

I'm trying to design a database system that is to be accessed via custom-built apps. At present, a web app is not planned for - but will consider in the future. The custom-built apps will be MacOSX, Windows, iOS and Android based.

I'm a complete noob with MySQL design. So, question is, is it better to design the MySQL database to allow remote connections (from the various apps) or should the database be accessed via a PHP based "portal"? What are the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going to have multiple client applications, you should expose the database via a Web API, usually a RESTful one. Zend's [ApiGility](http://www.apigility.org/) is one way to easily create them.  All your clients talk to the API endpoints to do things (add/edit/delete records, authenticate users, etc..). Your API handles the requests and updating your data store.

This has a number of benefits

1. Your clients just need to know how to talk to your API over HTTP.
2. You can easily allow more clients as new thigs emerge.
3. Your API handles data validation, & sanitization, which means your clients can do a little less work and are less prone to introducing their bugs as a result.
4. Your clients are agnostic about the back end. So if your app takes off and you need to scale out horizontally, they don't have to change. Or if you need to switch back end stores or add a caching layer between the API and DB all the changes are "behind the scenes" to them.

You'll want to read up and research a couple of things:

1. How to design a good REST API
2. How to handle client app authentication and security
3. Frameworks/approaches for building an API
4. Best way to exchange data between client and API. Or do you need multiple ways to represnt data? JSON is usually the best bet, but you might want to offer XML.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Will research on REST API.